# Unable to access Aws KMS service from amazon EKS pods

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms, amazon-eks

I have a kubernates pod which is trying to access the aws kms service using the aws java sdk to decrypt the password and I have the valid I am role attached to the pod but the request is failing with the below error,

```
{
"message": "Service Unavailable: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), 
SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@219aa2a6: profile file cannot be null, 
com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@399fc8ea: Internal Server Error (Service: null; Status Code: 500; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)]"
}
```

below is the code part which supposes to invoke the kms

```
private final boolean kmsEnabled;

private final AWSKMS kmsClient;

public KmsKeyManager(@Value("${kms.enabled}") final boolean kmsEnabled,
                     @Value("${kms.endpoint}") final String kmwEndPoint,
                     @Value("${aws.region}") final String awsRegion) {
    AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfig = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(kmwEndPoint, awsRegion);
    kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
            .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfig)
            .build();

    this.kmsEnabled = kmsEnabled;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message here contains the hint what is missing:

> Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain …

See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) how to provide the necessary credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to create a VPC endpoint since EKS pods may not have an external IP and thus will not be able to connect to KMS